# MaterialDesign ComboBox Arrow Resize And Change Color WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox, material-design-in-xaml

I'm working on changing this component but can't get it right at all. I've tried:

1. Using WPF functionality for

   1. "Style → Convert to new Resource.." - resulted in blank ComboBox from default code
   2. "Template → Convert to new Resource.." - resulted in weird ComboBox looking like default non-MaterialDesign one
2. Copying [this](https://github.com/MaterialDesignInXAML/MaterialDesignInXamlToolkit/blob/master/MainDemo.Wpf/ComboBoxes.xaml) to my resource dictionary and tried to edit it, but it needed a massive amount of converters and other things I couldn't get it working

The arrow currently looks like this, but this behavior is default and I want to make it a bit bigger, so it's more visible on the big screen and also change the color of the arrow itself
[image: it currently looks like this, but I want to make it a bit bigger, so it's more visible on big screen and also change the color]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `VisualTreeHelper` class to get a reference to the `Path` in the `ToggleButton` in the default template and then set its properties:

```
private void ComboBox_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ToggleButton toggleButton = FindVisualChild<ToggleButton>((ComboBox)sender);
    if (toggleButton != null)
    {
        Path path = FindVisualChild<Path>(toggleButton);
        if (path != null)
        {
            path.Width = 20;
            path.Height = 20;
            path.Fill = Brushes.Red;
        }
    }

}

private static T FindVisualChild<T>(Visual visual) where T : Visual
{
    for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(visual); i++)
    {
        Visual child = (Visual)VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(visual, i);
        if (child != null)
        {
            T correctlyTyped = child as T;
            if (correctlyTyped != null)
                return correctlyTyped;

            T descendent = FindVisualChild<T>(child);
            if (descendent != null)
                return descendent;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

**Sample XAML markup:**

```
<ComboBox Margin="100" Loaded="ComboBox_Loaded">
    <ComboBoxItem>1</ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem>2</ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem>3</ComboBoxItem>
</ComboBox>
```

**Result:**
[image]

The other option would be to copy the default templates from [here](https://github.com/MaterialDesignInXAML/MaterialDesignInXamlToolkit/blob/master/MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf/Themes/MaterialDesignTheme.ComboBox.xaml) and modify the `Path` element in the `MaterialDesignComboBoxToggleButton` resource. Beware that it requires you to copy and paste quite some XAML.